# Why use .takeUntil() over .take(1) with Http service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

**Context:** I am working on implementing [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) within an [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) project and studying the [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app).

**Question:** In the [BookEffects class file](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/book.ts#L50), line #50, why is `takeUntil(...)` used instead of `take(1)`?  Both would seem to accomplish the same thing in this case.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class BookEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private googleBooks: GoogleBooksService) { }

  @Effect()
  search$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(book.ActionTypes.SEARCH)
    .debounceTime(300)
    .map((action: book.SearchAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(query => {
      if (query === '') {
        return empty();
      }

      const nextSearch$ = this.actions$.ofType(book.ActionTypes.SEARCH).skip(1);

      return this.googleBooks.searchBooks(query)
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
        .map(books => new book.SearchCompleteAction(books))
        .catch(() => of(new book.SearchCompleteAction([])));
    });
}
```

And here is the [Google Books service file](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/services/google-books.ts#L8-L23):

```ts
@Injectable()
export class GoogleBooksService {
  private API_PATH: string = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  searchBooks(queryTitle: string): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_PATH}?q=${queryTitle}`)
      .map(res => res.json().items || []);
  }

  retrieveBook(volumeId: string): Observable<Book> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_PATH}/${volumeId}`)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code itself, rather than screenshots. And, BTW, you can include line numbers in GitHub links like [this](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/book.ts#L37-L54) (shift-click on the line numbers and the lines will be highlighted, etc.)

Comment: @cartant Fixed. I was only trying to include the line numbers HERE instead of making people click.  But thanks for the Github link tip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand why `takeUntil` is used, it might help to make no assumptions about the implementation of `searchBooks`.

The `searchBooks` service method returns an observable of `Book[]`. That observable does not necessarily have to complete; for instance, it could emit additional results if the database changes (this is what happens with Firebase's AngularFire2 observables). However, if `take(1)` is used, subsequent results will be ignored. If `takeUntil` is used, subsequent results will continue to effect actions until the next search is initiated.

However, I don't think the `takeUntil` is essential, as the `switchMap` will take care of things (the inner observable will be unsubscribed, etc.).

The author(s) of the `example-app` appear to have implemented the search effect in such a way that it is not dependent upon the implementation of the service.

With the simple, `Http`-based implementation of `searchBooks`, I cannot see why either `take(1)` or `takeUntil` would be required - as the observable will complete and the `switchMap` will ensure that `SearchCompleteAction` actions for stale searches are not emitted.

Comment: Great explanation.  Thanks for bashing me over the head with the **separation-of-concerns** hammer.

Comment: I'm no expert but I think a reason to prefer takeUntil is that if take(1) is used the subscription will not be unsubscribed if the observable never emits.

Answer (score -2):

**take(n)** returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of an observable sequence

**takeUntil(Observable | Promise)** Returns the values from the source observable sequence until the other observable sequence or Promise produces a value.You should probably be using `takeUntil` to manage your RxJS subscriptions.

1) it fires a completion event when you kill your stream

2) fewer actual points of subscription (because fewer calls to `subscribe`)

for more info read this article https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.ge4d447b6

Comment: Not helpful.  Yes, I get the differences between .take() and .takeUntil() but in this specific case we are dealing with an Http get request.  Both should work since we know Http.get is only going to fire once, right?.  And to your points: 1)  .take(1) also fires a completion event, and 2) it does not yield any more points of subscription.  The article is good but doesn't address my question -- why *in this specific case* do we not use .take(1)?  That article even mentions using .take(n) as an alternative!