# Why takeUntil is necessary in this ngrx example?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In this [rxjs example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/book.ts), a `takeUntil` is used in the `switchMap` section. I removed it and the observable works fine.

Why the `takeUntil` and the `nextSearch$` are necessary in this [example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/book.ts)?

```
@Injectable()
export class BookEffects {

  @Effect()
  search$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(book.ActionTypes.SEARCH)
    .debounceTime(300)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(query => {
      if (query === '') {
        return empty();
      }

      const nextSearch$ = this.actions$.ofType(book.ActionTypes.SEARCH).skip(1);

      return this.googleBooks.searchBooks(query)
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
        .map(books => new book.SearchCompleteAction(books))
        .catch(() => of(new book.SearchCompleteAction([])));
    });

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private googleBooks: GoogleBooksService) { }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use .takeUntil() over .take(1) with Http service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657400/why-use-takeuntil-over-take1-with-http-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `takeUntil` here is used to convert the Observable returned by `GoogleBooksService.searchBooks()` to a new Observable, which will be interrupted (i.e. prematurely completed) if the auxiliary observable emits anything (a new search request action by the user, by the looks of it) before `searchBooks` returns a result, effectively preventing the subscription to ever trigger. It won't make a difference if the http request behind `searchBooks` finishes before the user makes a new request, which will also complete the observable, but only *after* triggering the subscription. This should be the case 95% of the time.

The `takeUntil` waits until a second Observable emits something (here this would be the *next* SEARCH action by the user, I presume, with the *current* one being skipped using `skip(1)`) and then closes the Observable, destroying the subscription to it before it is triggered, probably because a new BookEffects is instantiated to take care of that new search.

Disclaimer: I did not go through all of the application's source code so some of this is guesswork, but I'm confident it goes in the right direction, at least.

Comment: Whether or not the observable returned by `searchBooks` is hot or cold is not relevant; it's whether or not it completes that's important. And `takeUntil` is used to ensure that it does complete. BTW, `searchBooks` is implemented using the `Http` service, which returns a cold observable - that is, no HTTP request is made until `subscribe` is called.

Comment: You're right, I was too quick to assume it'd be a hot observable, these are most commonly the ones you need to ensure completion for. The core purpose of the takeUntil mentioned in my answer is still correct, although it won't prevent any memory leaks here but rather just improve flickering search results or something...

Comment: Yep, the core of your answer is correct. I just wanted to clarify the hot/cold issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer taking this into account and focusing on the core.

Comment: I added a ```do``` method and logged the sequence. I see that if I don't use takeUntil, the google API will be called for whatever I type, does not matter how fast I type. If I use takeUntil, and type fast, I see only one call to the google API.

Comment: I thought the point of using `switchMap` was what `takeUntil` does here, to cancel the inner observable when the outer observable emits a new value? They're both the same action, so a second search would cause `switchMap` to cancel its inner observable, basically what `takeUntil` does manually?